# What is the meaning of 看 in 比如，他们讨论过《卖火柴的小女孩儿》是写给谁看的？

Tags: translation, meaning, meaning-in-context

我曾经听一位美国的小学老师说，他们十分重视和学生一起讨论问题。比如，他们讨论过《卖火柴的小女孩儿》是写给谁看的，还讨论过灰姑娘的故事。

This is from the Standard Course Book of HSK5, chapter 22. What is the meaning of 看 here: 是写给谁看的？Maybe to consider?:

比如 (for example)，他们(they)讨论过(discussed)《卖火柴的小女孩儿》(the Little Match Girl) 是(is)写(written)给(by)谁(whom)看(to consider)的

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

看 means "read" here

The word for "read" is 读 in Chinese, therefore, "read book" should be translated as "读书". However, the term "读书" mostly means "study", and "读" itself has the meaning of "vocally read out"

To avoid confusion, people often say "看(童话)书, 看小說, 看报纸" instead of "读(童话)书, 读小說, 读报纸" to make it clear you are reading with your eyes only, not reading the words out loud from the book, novel, or newspaper

> 比如 (for example)，他们(they)讨论过(discussed)《卖火柴的小女孩儿》(the Little Match Girl) 是(is)写(written)给(for)谁(whom)看(to read)的

Comment: For example, they discussed the Little Match Girl is written by whom to read. How to make this make sense?

Comment: 写给谁 = written for whom, not "written by whom"